# Way to differentiate multiple divs with same class or ID when Javascript is run

Tags: javascript, html

I am generating QR codes for [id] on an invoice.

Right now I have a javascript at each place where there is going to be a qr code to run, and generate the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function makeCode (data,width) {    
var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById(data), {
    width : width,
    height : width
});

    var length = (data).length;

        if (length===10) {qrcode.makeCode("10" + data);}
        else {qrcode.makeCode(data);}
}
</script>
```

```html
<div id="[id]"></div><script>makeCode("[id]","50")</script>
```

The reason I have to use [id] as the "id" of the div is that it's the only piece of dynamic content I get for the item.

The issue is that when I have more than one item with the same [id] the javascript is of course stacking up all the QR codes into the first `<div>` with that id.

Is there a way to have the javascript know that it was run from the third DIV (as an example) and then put the code into the third DIV, instead of the first.

I know that you're not supposed to have more than one div with the same ID element. That's part of the issue, I am trying to make them unique but I dont know how.

I have added a jfiddle so you can see the issue a little more clearly.

https://jsfiddle.net/nmteaco/x57o9pko/3/

Comment: should not have duplicate `id` on a single page use `data-attribute` instead? something like `<div class="qrCode" data-id="[id]" data-index="1"></div>`

Comment: I know there should not be multiple of the same ID, that's where the issue is coming in. I'm asking how to generate a unique id when all I get is the identical [id] (when two items have the same id in our system).

Comment: perhaps make up a jsfiddle demo and we can have a look at what is going on?

Comment: Thats a great Idea... thank you. I will make the jfiddle and update the question.

Comment: Here is the jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nmteaco/x57o9pko/3/

Comment: hum.. having same js function call script on every table is not good, and benefit of table for a single item row per table isnt good either

Comment: how does the table being populated?? js to call server to receive and js to append the table right?

Comment: qrcode is generated on page load? or by click event?

Comment: I dont have control over how the repeating elements (like the products) are repeated. The shopping cart just duplicates everything within the tags. So I can make the "items" unique by using the [id], but they become ununique when the item [id] is the same.

Comment: It is generated on page load. (Stackoverflow is telling me to move this to chat, but then not letting me chat, since I have a low reputation)

Comment: since the way the html is set out like that, it is really hard to dynamically use the function..should be one `table` many `tr` and one `script`

Comment: and `script` function should run once and looping through every `tr` within the `table` and create qrcode

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to this:

```
<div data-content="qr-content" data-value="Your qr content"></div>
    <script>
       var elements = document.queryselectorall('[data-content="qr-content"]');
       for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
           makeCode(elements[i].getAttribute('data-value'), 50);
        }
   </script>
```

Comment: Thank you... where do I specify what the [id] (the product number) is of the div I want to generate the QR code for? would this code just turn whatever is in the div to a qrcode?

Comment: You are right. I just updated the code. Please check it out and let me know. If you found it useful, don't forget to vote up.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, few things in your current website logic needs to adjust to more dynamic.

First, should have one `table` which represent shopping cart and within that cart, you can have multiple `rows` of items for QRcode generation. And each same `id` can have a indexing flag 1..2..3..

I have made a demo of how your issue can be fixed with change of your html structure.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/thefto_dev/d1y3e30n/)

Let me know what you think.

Comment: I am working on a page that prints invoices... the solution would work for one invoice, but the issue is that there are many invoices, so I can't have all products in a single table. At best each order could have a single table. But since the page displays multiple invoices, the issues arises when more then one person order the same item.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how this worked...

However adding a class to the products of "product" and posting the following code at the end of the document worked.

```
    $.each($(".product"), function(index, value){
    var num = index + 1;
    $(value).attr("id","qrcode"+ num);
});
```

It makes each id unique after it runs. However somehow the qr javascript still knows which div to put the correct image into.